# How to generate total for each section in a column in pivot table on Qliksense?

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm new to Qliksense and I'm trying to generate a table as shown below. Using the Pivot table, I came up with getting near the structure, but could not add the **Total** row for **Amount** as shown for each unique value in **Name**. How can I add that?

[image: Required format]

Answer (score 1):

Expand the dimension tab under Data about halfway down you'll see a slider to put totals on and off.

[image]